# Count Number of rows in table using lambda expression

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to programming, can someone please help me...

```
<div>
    <h5>Total Number of Classes = @Model.Count(i => i.Class_ID)</h5>
</div>
```

How to solve this.. below image shows the error error cs1662 and cs0029
[image: below image shows the error error cs1662 and cs0029]

this is the model

//  namespace School_ManagementSystem.Models
{

```
[Table("Tbl_Class")]

public class ClassModel
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Class ID")]
    public string Class_ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Lecturer")]
    [DisplayName("Lecturer")]
    public string Lecturer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select the Start Date.")]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select the End Date.")]
    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide a Valid Student Count")]
    [DisplayName("Student Limit")]
    public int Student_Count { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Status.")]
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Course.")]
    [DisplayName("Course")]
    public string Course_ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Subject.")]
    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    public string Subject_ID { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: What does your model look like?

Answer (score 0):

The Count LINQ function counts the number of rows where the lambda evaluates to TRUE.

```
// Count the number of records where the column is equal to 5
@Model.Count(x => x.SomeNumber == 5);
// Count the number of rows where some text contains some other text
@Model.Count(x => x.SomeText.Contains(“Something”));
```

The error is telling you that your lambda does not evaluate to a Boolean because i.Class_ID is just a property.

If you want to count the number of distinct classes, you should use CountDistinct:

```
@Model.CountDistinct(x => x.Class_ID);
```

If you want to could the number of classes regardless of the duplications, you should not pass a lambda:

```
@Model.Count();
```

Comment: thank you soo much... "S. Walker" it worked

Comment: I also do not understand why this question was closed.. It seems reasonably detailed to me.

Comment: Thank you soo much... @S. Walker  it worked.. I wanted this @Model.Count();  In addition how can I add a where Clause to it like(Get Count where Status == "Active")

Comment: @Model.Count(x => x.Status == “Active”)

Comment: Thank you soo much @S. Walker... your answer worked.... I also found a way like this @Model.Where(m => m.Status == "Active").Count()  all thanks to you... god bless

Comment: Be aware when using LINQ that each LINQ statement corresponds to a separate Database query. So your code and mine would produce the same SQL, if you called my code and your code as two separate calls, it would result in two SQL statements. Just something to be mindful of if that makes sense. 

Although that’s only applicable in the Controller, not the View.

Comment: Yes I understood … thank you for your valuable advice @S. Walker

Comment: --@S. Walker-- another problem sorry for my trouble... How to get sum @Model.Sum(x => x.Payment_Status == "Successful") this code block is showing an error..how to fix it

Comment: What are you trying to Sum? Ask another question.

Comment: there is another payment model ... i want add all the payments where the payment status = to  Successful

Comment: You need to use Where(x => x.Status == “Successful”).Sum(x => x.PaymentTotal)

Comment: Your Solution Worked... Thank you very much --@S. Walker-- you are Amazing... May All your Dreams Come True :)